# Taskbar hangs when opening a folder

Tags: usb, taskbar, freeze, usb-flash-drive

Any one in here who has experienced this problem. The taskbar hangs whenever I:

1. Open a folder from a browser
2. Open a usb flash drive
3. Open a drive on my computer

It really sucks, but the solution to the taskbar hangs because of opening flash drive is to remove the flash drive. Which is not safe because the file system of my flash drive is ntfs. And I can't just safely remove it because the taskbar doesn't respond when I click it.
Do you know any solutions to this? Other than disabling the automatically search for printer in the folder options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to the second tab in Folder Options and check Open Folder Windows in Separate Process, which will confine the hang to that explorer window but use a little more memory.